# How to blur current activity, but don't blur menu-info

Tags: java, android, button, menu, styles

I want to blur the Activiti when opening on top of it the second Activiti, but do not want to obscure the menu item "ic_dialog_info" and one of the buttons from the past Activiti. How can I do that? I can do this through the styles?

It does not work -->

```
<style name="CustomOverFloatMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackgroud</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverFloatMenu</item>
        <!--<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverFloatMenu</item>-->
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible ways.  You could arrange the first activity/screen into panes and only blur some of the panes, keeping the menu and button unblurred.

More complex would be using three layers.  Blur the first screen completely.  Then put on an intermediate unblurred layer, which is transparent except for the button and menu you want to show and correctly positioned to cover their blurred equivalents.  Any allowed actions are passed through to the original screen.  Your second screen can be added over the transparent intermediate screen.